# ¿Cómo crear un ejecutable para mi aplicación hecha en Jython?

Tags: django, sqlite3

Tengo una aplicación web en el framework django , jython y uso la base de datos SQLite.

La aplicación la ejecuto por consola ubicándome en la carpeta y poniendo la siguiente instrucción:

```
jython manage.py runserver
```

y luego entrar a Internet y poner `127.0.0.1:8000/`, antes de esto, debo también editar las variables de entorno (`path` y `classpath`).

Pero lo que yo quería es crear una aplicación de escritorio (un ejecutable), osea que al hacer doble clic entre directamente a la página web. Agradecería mucho su ayuda ya que no lo puedo resolver de ninguna forma.

Comment: Podrías hacer un script (un bat o un powershell, hablando de windows ) que al ejecutarlo lance el servidor, y un tiempo prudencial después el navegador con la url de acceso a tú aplicación. Pienso que es la forma más sencilla de hacerlo.

Comment: me podrias ayudar a hacer eso ya que nose como se hace? por facebook o por mail nose ...

Comment: Hasta el lunes estoy sin ordenador (escribo desde el móvil) y me es muy complicado escribir. En cuanto pueda te recomiendo alguna documentación.

Comment: lo que te sugieren de hacer un script y levantar *el servidor de desarrollo* podría ser una alternativa, pero dependiendo de lo que quires hacer, podria no ser tan buena. ¿que necesitas hacer puntualmente? ¿es un sistema "de bolsillo" y que solo tu usaras? De otra forma, no le encuentro mucho sentido.